# URL unknown chars are added to request data

Tags: jquery, http

I want to send an URL to a server. The URL is encrypted and the server will recognize it. Unfortunately some chars are added to the URL, here: /event/seq/1/onclick. How did this happen? I am using JQuery, maybe that is responsible for this behaviour? Thanks in advance.

https://xxx.xxx.xx:8445/m4idat/jsp/remote/remotelogin.jsf?params=wMeqn%2BszV9PZd4petW%2B8cMbVHm34j5Q4e8qEGBFErqx8uIKiC0LezhJxWJzdYKUG4ISHkbgDGah0b1%2FpX14BXCsA%2FjMe4MJ3S7rL28HACgb0mfh8xqJDEubgbsWDZ2Wy8l2qAUHtQ2uyJ2TucbiUMZwhkiJYgy0ph9ciLLBaTfuI9Ax%2Bpv7bMs7MbqXIkbkb5GKmRTbjYV%2FUIQYUxbWsxg%3D%3D/event/seq/1/onclick

Comment: We can't help unless you show us the code that is generating the URL to be sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see exactly what happens in jquery (and javascript in general) by adding a breakpoint just before the problematic call in Firebug or the built-in Chrome Inspector debugger.
Then follow the execution step by step, while watching the value of the variables of interest.

You can even switch to a non-minified "debug" jquery file while you do this just in case you end up tracing into jquery itself.